# URL gets truncated when inserted into mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql

A AWS url stored as a string variable in c# windows application gets truncated when inserted into MySql database table. I don't see it truncated while debugging, the variable contains the entire url. The column data type is Varchar(2083). Tried Text too. Any idea whats happening? Please help me out. Thanks.

```
  string UrlLinkABC= null;
  if (FilePathABC != null) 
            {
                   UrlLinkABC =   ZipUploadTheLogs.GetTheLogs(StartTime, EndTime, "ABC", FilePathABC);
            }
  Test tst = new Test();

  tst.UrlLinkABC=UrlLinkABC ;
  ConnectionDb.InsertTest(tst)
```

ConnectionDb class:

```
    public static int InsertTest(Test test)
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("STP_UPDATE_TEST", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //update the test object of the Test Class
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_ABCLOG", test.UrlLinkABC );
            conn.Open();

            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }

            return i;
}
```

MySQL Database Stored procedure:

```
 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `STP_UPDATE_TEST`(
 ,IN _ABCLOG VARCHAR(30)
 )
 BEGIN

                       INSERT INTO TESTRESULTS( UrlLinkABC)
                       VALUES(_ABCLOG );                                
 END
```

Comment: Unless you show us the code you are using, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Just added the code....Please take a look

Comment: Cool... How did I overlook this? Thanks... I don't have enough reputation to rate your answer. thanks for help.It is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the stored proc.  It's accepting an input of `varchar(30)` anything after the 30 characters is being truncated and not passed through.  Change that to match the database character size and you'll be golden

Comment: Thanks @user2366842, your help is well appreciated.